# Tag mismatch error with ssl android studio - problem with wifi

Tags: java, android, flutter, android-studio

Packages to install:

- Android Emulator (emulator)

Preparing "Install Android Emulator (revision: 30.5.4)".
Downloading https://dl.google.com/android/repository/emulator-windows_x64-7243153.zip
An error occurred while preparing SDK package Android Emulator: Tag mismatch!.
"Install Android Emulator (revision: 30.5.4)" failed.
Failed packages:

- Android Emulator (emulator)

I am getting such errors while downloading or updating anything in android studio.

but when I connect with my mobile data it works.

so maybe the problem is with my wifi.

also when I download anything in google chrome it says network failure again and again even if the internet speed is 30mbps.

My internet connection is very good but maybe it's a problem with the firewall or something.

Comment: Are you working with proxy that intercepts SSL traffic? You can check it by browsing to google.com and check if its certificate is signed by custom root CA certificate

Comment: yes yes i work with proxy sometimes the thing is i point some remote apis to the localhost

Comment: I’m guessing that proxy performs SSL Inspection so you should either disable the SSL Inspection if you’re the owner of the proxy or add the custom root CA certificate to Android Studio + JRE. I’ll write my answer assuming the proxy performs SSL inspection.

Comment: ok, I disabled the proxy and it solved my problem.

thank you so much for your help.

Answer (score 4):

Long time ago, I struggled with the same thing until I came up with a solution.

I assume your proxy performs SSL Inspection using custom root CA certificate and by doing so, Android Studio and/or JRE does troubles.

First, you need to export that custom certificate to a file:
Simply browser to some site (let’s say [www.google.com](http://www.google.com)), then download the **root** certificate to a file.
Found some instructions online:
https://www.esri.com/arcgis-blog/products/bus-analyst/field-mobility/learn-how-to-download-a-ssl-certificate-for-a-secured-portal/

Second, get Android Studio to trust this certificate by adding it to accepted certificates list in Server Certificate preferences section.

Now configure your proxy in HTTP Proxy preferences section - I believe “Auto-detect proxy settings” is enough.

Finally, and that’s the hard part, get your JRE to trust the certificate. Locate your JDK folder (File -> Project Structure), then install the certificate to the JRE’s key store.

Windows CMD (password is `changeit`):
`keytool.exe -importcert -alias MY_ALIAS -file PATH_TO_CERT_FILE -keystore PATH_TO_JDK_FOLDER\jre\lib\security\cacert`

Mac terminal (password is also `changeit`):
`sudo keytool -import -alias MY_ALIAS -file PATH_TO_CERT_FILE -keystore PATH_TO_JDK_FOLDER/Contents/Home/jre/lib/security/cacerts`

Crossing my fingers that it’ll work :)
If not, I’ll delete my answer so please keep me posted.

Comment: Chapeu. It's pretty embarassing a similar problem. On Windows and on Ubuntu too